# Use local apache API from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I have developed an `API` which is available locally on `loc.api` and on production on `live.api` (obviously the domains are just an example).
The API runs locally on a classic apache server.

Now I am playing with `Laravel`, using this `API`. No problem connecting to `live.api` (as I am using the real domain), but fails to connect to my `local API`.

I am guessing it is just a `host` config issue, as `Homestead` fails to connect to my normal apache server on my cumputer.
If that is the case, I should just have to define an `IP` linked to `loc.api`, but I have no idea what IP I should use there.

So to recapitulate, no problem running `loc.api` on my local `apache` server, no problem running live.api, no problem running `Laravel` on its own or connected to `live.api`, but can't seem to get `Laravel` to work with my `loc.api`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Not 100% sure if this will be helpful but homestead runs on something akin to a virtual machine so you need to make sure that you use the virtual machine's default gateway IP as the API IP. You can also host the API within homestead probably.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think if I can't find any easier solution, I will have to host my loc.api on homestead as well, but would like to avoid that as I would got the database twice I guess. I will try the gateway IP now !

Comment: if you set up your API with a virtual host you'd need to create an entry in the virtual machine's `/etc/host` which would read something like `<gateway IP> <local.api DNS>` and then you can use the DNS normally.

Comment: Thanks apokryfos, it worked :) if you want to put it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homestead runs on something akin to a virtual machine. The virtual machine's localhost is indeed the local IP address used internally within the virtual machine. In order to communicate with the host machine (the machine running the virtual machine) you need to use the default gateway IP address. This is the IP address which the virtual machine uses to refer to its host system.

The default varies depending on the configuration of the virtual machine. Ideally, if you've setup your API normally on your localhost and access it locally via 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) then setting your local site configuration to the default gateway will work.

However, if you set up your API through a virtual host and you access it via `local.api` or some host like this you need to modify your virtual machine's `/etc/hosts` file (since homestead is serving an Ubuntu OS) and enter a line like

```
<gateway IP> local.api
```

This way you can use `local.api` as your API host address which will resolve to the gateway IP and call the API using the correct hostname.